# Sql Server2005 problem

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **EXACT** duplicate of [Sql Server2005 query problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993927/sql-server2005-query-problem)

i have a table which contains the following fields

•Supervisorid
•Empid
This is just like a referral program. A guy can refer 3 guys under him i.e, 3 is referring three guys namely 4 5 8 similarly 4 is referring 9 10 and 11 likewise 8 is referring 12, 13 it goes like this..

I want a query to get all EmpId under Supervisor 3

Comment: If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, YOU should invest some time in asking the question.

Comment: **EXACT** duplicate of [Sql Server2005 query problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993927/sql-server2005-query-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/hierarchies_in_sql_server_databases.htm). It uses recursive store procedure so referring level will be limited .

A non recursive store procedure call [solution](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q248915).

With SQL2005 you can use Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions:

```
 WITH Report(Supervisorid , Empid , Title, Level)
    AS
    (
    -- Anchor member definition
        SELECT e.Supervisorid , e.Empid , e.Title,   0 AS Level
        FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
        WHERE Supervisorid = 3
        UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member definition
        SELECT e.Supervisorid , e.Empid , e.Title,   Level + 1
        FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
        INNER JOIN Report AS d
            ON e.Supervisorid = d.Empid 
    )
    -- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT Supervisorid , Empid , Title, Level
FROM Report;
```