# Recursive query

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I have a table which contains the following fields

- Supervisorid
- Empid

This is just like a referral program. A guy can refer 3 guys under him i.e, 3 is referring three guys namely 4 5 8 similarly 4 is referring 9 10 and 11 likewise 8 is referring 12, 13 it goes like this..

I want a query to get all EmpId under Supervisor 3

Comment: I.e. you want to have 4,5,8,9,10,11,12,13, right?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108/is-it-possible-to-make-a-recursive-sql-query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server2005 query problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993927/sql-server2005-query-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want us to write the solution for you, or explain a bit how recursive queries can be built up ?

An example of how they are built up is on http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8//topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/samples/clp/s-flt-db2.htm.

The IBM DB2 redbook has an entire chapter on SQL recursion.

The gist is that the following steps are generally involved:

- you define a "seed".  SELECT SUPID, EMPID, 1 AS LVL FROM EMP WHERE SUPID = 3;
- you assign to this a name.  WITH SRC AS <your seed here>
- you define the way to go to the 'next level', starting from the seed, using the assigned name.   SELECT SRC.SUPID, F.EMPID, SRC.LVL+1 FROM SRC, EMP WHERE SRC.EMPID=EMP.SUPID
- you combine the two together (inside the WITH clause)  WITH SRC AS <your seed here> UNION ALL <the other SELECT here>
- (optionally) you define which columns to select.  SELECT EMPID, LVL FROM SRC.